# Updating VSTO Add-In from a server

Tags: vb.net, deployment, vsto, outlook-addin, clickonce

I used ClickOnce on a FTP server to deploy my Outlook add-in but I don't know if I'm doing it well...

[image: Publish parameters]

After publishing the update of the VSTO to a server using ClickOnce and installing it in my developing computer, the updated VSTO **detects automatically the update**.

Then I tried to deploy it on another computer. Deployment worked but it **doesn't detect updates** when i restart Outlook after a new publish.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I try to create an add-in that updates automatically when i do changes. But as my solution needs to be deployed on many computers, I want to do it remotly. I thought this was the way to do it but if someone has a better option, I will be thanksfull.

Comment: Could anyone here point me to the solution? I read many threads on ClickOnce but can't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Too many possible factors. See [Troubleshoot Office solution deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/troubleshooting-office-solution-deployment?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already looked to troubleshoot list. Do you understand what I try to do here? Have you ever deployed on a server to have automatical updates? There is something i miss but can't understand...

Comment: Of course, I do. I'd suggest making sure the update was published after installing the add-in on the end-user machine. Then you may use Fiddler for tracking what requests and responses are sent.